# Circle tangent to another line and another circle

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I am looking for an algorithm, with an example in pseudocode,  to find a circle `c1(c1x,c1y)` with a given radius `r` tangent to a line  `l` and another circle `c2(c2x,c2y)`; this circle is tangent to the same line.

Thanks,

Comment: It is not clear what parameters are known

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the one hand, the locus of the points at distance r2 from the first circle, is the circle of the radius of (r1+r2) at the same center (**C**) as the first circle. OTOH, it is a line, parallel to the given line (**A B**) at the offset distance of r2. Their intersection (**F**) is the center of the sought-for circle.

[image]

There are two such intersection points, obviously.

Another possibility is to have the two circles touch at the point (**D**) where the first circle touches the line. To find such second circle's center (**E**), just lengthen the radius of (c1,r1) circle "down" (on the diagram) by (r2-r1).

I.e. to find **E**, go "down" from point **C** the distance of `(r2-r1)` (signed). To find **F**, go "right" the distance of `sqrt( (r1+r2)^2 - (r1-r2)^2 ) == 2*sqrt(r1*r2)` from **E**.

Comment: I would add that there are 2 intersections on this line. There is also another locus on the other side of the line, and another one which defines the circle around the first one. (this last one is the intersection of the r2 parallel and the circle of radius abs(r1-r2))

Comment: @njzk2 have you missed that the c1,r1 circle (black) is also tangent to the given (black) line? The only way to have one circle inside the other as far as I can see is when the two circles touch at the same point on the given line. In which case no intersection need be sought.

Comment: yes, they touch the line at the same point that was my point. I think that matches the definition as well

Comment: @njzk2 OK, got it. :) So, just lengthening/shortening the radius line is enough (i.e. building one vector of length (r2-r1) at a given angle (line_angle - 90d) from the 1st center).

Answer (score 0):

Choose any point on the line, draw a perpendicular of length r on either side of the line. So one extremity of the perpendicular is on the line, and the other, is the center of the circle. Choose another point on the line, do the same thing.